# Parsing decoded JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have managed to decode some JSON in PHP successfully (not as painful as I thought), but it's been such a long time since I've done any real PHP, my brain has drawn a blank on the following.

The decoded json looks like this

```
[Array]
item {
      [0]
      {
         [live]=>
         [name]=>Paul
         [value]=>10
      }
      [1]
      {
         [live]=>1
         [name]=>Fred
         [value]=>32
      }
```

and so on

The problem I'm having is this - I'm trying to iterate through the structure to test first if live==1 and then if it's the first live name, to output it as a selected value to a HTML drop down.

I'm currently trying like this

```
$t = 0;
$count = 0;
foreach($decode['items'] as $option=>$value)
{
print_r("option = $option\n");
    if ($option=>isLive == 1)   
{
    print_r("isLive is true for $option[$count]['names']\n");
        if ($t == 0)
        {
        echo "<option value=$option[name] selected>$value[name]</option>";
        $t = 1;
    }
    else
        echo "<option value=$option[name]>$value[name]</option>";
    }  
    else 
    {
    print_r("isLive is false for $option[$count]=>name\n");
    }
    $count++;
}
```

the problem is that I don't seem to be able to get the if statement correct for this to work. This is probably a seriously simple problem and will no doubt make me face palm, but I could do with a pointer in the right direction here!

Comment: `$option` is the key, you're looking for `if ($value['live'] == 1)`

Comment: `if ($value->live == 1 && $option == 0)`  is i think what you want

Comment: Make that `$value['live'] == 1` (or `$value->live` if it's an object, unclear from the question). Additionally, `$option=>isLive` is invalid syntax. While we appreciate your showing us what you are working with, please do check that code examples at least compile.

Comment: managed how? PHP 5.2+ has JSON parsing built in, http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

If the json is like you showed us you could not iterate over anything with your foreach because your array does not contain a key named `items`.

Using the provided structure this should do the trick:

```
foreach($decode["item"] as $item) {
    if($item->live == 1) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

If `$item` is not an object use `$item['live']` instead.

P.S.: You should really turn error_reporting on. `$option=>isLive` is no valid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
$t = 0;
$count = 0;

$arr = json_decode($json,true);
foreach($arr as $key=>$val)
{
  print_r($key);
  if($val['live'])
  {
   if($t == 0)
   {
     echo '<option value='.$val['name'].' selected>'.$val['name'].'</option>';
     $t = 1;
   }
   else
   {
     echo '<option value='.$val['name'].'>'.$val['name'].'</option>';
   }
  }
  else
  {
    echo $key.' not printed cause it hasn\'t live set to true';
  }
  $count++;
}
```

Comment: There is no `isLive` key in item.

Comment: He edited his question, there was... (i edited my answer now)